# Como ordenar linhas de um data frame?

Tags: r

Tenho um data frame chamando brca2 e queria ordenar os valores contidos na coluna radius_mean de forma decrescente (do maior para o menor). Usei o seguinte comando que vi em uma apostila mas não funciona.

```
# Ordenando linhas
brca2 <- brca2[order(brca$radius_mean, decreasing = T),]
View(brca2)
```

[Saída](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spI7P.png)

Comment: Esse código deveria ordenar a base. Imagens não são uma boa maneira de por dados, veja este [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Pode, por favor, [editar a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63437490/edit) com a saída de `dput(brca2)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(brca2, 20))`?

Comment: Uma possibilidade é ter atribuído um valor a uma variável `T`. Tente outra vez com `decreasing = TRUE`. Ou primeiro verifique `ls(pattern = "^T$")`, se existir, `rm(T)` e depois o código da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é usar o *arrange* da biblioteca *dplyr* para ordenar seu data frame de acordo com a coluna que deseja, com a opção desc() pode colocar a coluna de em ordem decrescente.

```
library(dplyr)      
arrange(brca,desc(brca$radius_mean))
```